# No sound when displaying notification

Tags: android

My app won't play any sound (or vibrate) when I display notification.

Notification code:

```
Uri sound = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI;

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSound(sound, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Notification manager:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelName = getChannelName(channel);
            Uri sound = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI;

            AudioAttributes attribute = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mChannel.setSound(sound, attribute);

            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
        }
```

I've looked at many older questions, but I didn't find any solution.

I test this on android 9.0.0

Comment: Does it work if you uninstall/reinstall the app?

Answer (score 0):

You create a `Notification.Builder` but you never create a `Notification`... Use `Builder.build()` to get one.
As well, you get a `NotificationManager` but you never as kit to display a `Notification`. To do this, use `manager.notify()`.

Comment: It was not visible is the code shown. I suppose you supply the correct parameters to the `notify` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may have set some other priority for notification channel.